# Session Start and Stop Error Php

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-cookies

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');
include('login_helper.php'); 
?>

<!--

html form

-->

Login/Logout Links depending on session state:
<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1){
        echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
        echo 'userID '.$userid;
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

**check_buyer.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); #recall session from index.php where user logged include()
require_once('login_helper.php');
/*
function validateUser()
{
    session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['valid'] == 1;
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
}
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}
*/

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');
$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Can't Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$LoginUserName = $_POST['userName'];
$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
//connect to the database here
$LoginUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($LoginUserName);
$query = "SELECT uID, uUPass, dynamSalt
        FROM User
        WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such USER exists
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}
$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$dynamSalt = $ifUserExists['dynamSalt'];  #get value of dynamSalt in query above
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$LoginPassword); #recreate originally created dynamic, unique pass

if($SaltyPass != $ifUserExists['uUPass']) # incorrect PASS
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}

else {
validateUser();
}
//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    echo "<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'; url=index.php'>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>";
    die();
}

?>
```

**login_helper.php**

```
<?php
 function validateUser()
{
    #session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['valid'] == 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $userid;
    echo "Session made";
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}

function logout()
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array(); //destroy all of the session variables
    session_destroy();
   echo "
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'; url=index.php'>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <html>";
}
?>
```

**pwhome.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}

//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>

<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1){
        echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
        echo 'userID '.$userid;
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php    
require_once('login_helper.php');
logout();
?>
```

Current State: When I visit `index.php` and login with credentials that are indeed correct, I get a never ending refresh of `check_buyer.php`

How do I get this to login in properly (from index.php) and redirect me properly to pwhome.php upon providing valid credentials on index.php ?

Comment: is the filename logout.php or Logout.php?

Comment: where did you log out? At index.php or at check_buyer.php?

Comment: Trying to have it, so they login on index.php, it refreshes that page and goes back to index.php with the link "logout" appearing. Does that make sense?

Comment: If they click logout, it refreshes index.php again and then displays "Login" appearing

Comment: You can go to /var/lib/php/session to check if new session file is being created if you are using linux

Comment: Is there another way to do this? Im running it locally.

Comment: There is nothing wrong to have a login on index page, validate on another page and redirect back to index. Are you seeing the user id below the logout link? If yes, then your session is working.

Comment: Do I need to use something like SESS_MEMBER_ID ?

Comment: Then can you replace `$userid` with `$_SESSION['uID']` and try that again?

Comment: I switched this in index.php, it didnt do anything.

Comment: If the link to logout is there on your index page, I think the session is working. Probably you didn't define `$userid` in your check_buyer.php page.

Comment: $userid is defined and utilized in `check_buyer.php` . its defined as a function and called at the end of the script its part of the `validateUser()` function. See anything else??

Comment: On a second thought too, I thought Login was appearing once i clear browser history and restarted browser, but it isnt. The Logout link ALWAYS appears.

Comment: Calling a function is different from defining a variable. See how you define `$dynamSalt` in check_buyer.php. If logout link always appear, how do you login?

Comment: See updated code. I can logout, but not login..

Comment: Then I suggest you check and see whether the web server has read and execute access to logout.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder with your code, if you want to logout and refresh the index.php with new session value, why dont you put `header( 'Location: index.php' );` in your logout function?

So, i think this probably will help, modify your **logout.php**:

**Logout.php**

```
<?php  
session_start();
function logout()
{
  $_SESSION = array(); //destroy all of the session variables
  session_destroy();
  echo "logged out?";
  header( 'Location: index.php' );
}

logout();
?>
```

**Last Edited :**

Try this codes :

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');
?>

<!-- 

html form 

-->

<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1){
        echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
        echo 'userID '.$userid;
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

**check_buyer.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); #recall session from index.php where user logged include()

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');
$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Can't Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$LoginUserName = $_POST['userName'];
$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
//connect to the database here
$LoginUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($LoginUserName);
$query = "SELECT uID, uUPass, dynamSalt
        FROM User
        WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such USER exists
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}
$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$dynamSalt = $ifUserExists['dynamSalt'];  #get value of dynamSalt in query above
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$LoginPassword); #recreate originally created dynamic, unique pass

if($SaltyPass != $ifUserExists['uUPass']) # incorrect PASS
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}

else {
validateUser();
}
//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}

function validateUser()
{
    session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $userid;
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php    
session_start();
function logout()
{
    $_SESSION = array(); //destroy all of the session variables
    session_destroy();
    header( 'Location: index.php' );
}
logout();
?>
```

Comment: I wanna make sure, when do you run **check_buyer.php** ? and why do you make two function of logout? you can make it simple by removing logout function from your **check_buyer.php**.

Comment: `check_buyer.php` is called when the `username` and `password` are provided on `index.php`. I removed the `logout()` function on `check_buyer.php`

Comment: `Call to undefined function validateUser() /check_buyer.php on line 31` that line is: `else {
validateUser();
}`

Comment: add `include('login_helper.php');` in your `check_buyer.php` too.

Comment: Did that.  i get this when trying to login: `Warning: session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent in login_helper.php on line 4` when it goes to `check_buyer.php` when `username` and `password` are submitted.

Comment: you can comment first that lines `session_regenerate_id();`, if it works than it can be clear what the problem was.

Comment: Now it goes through without complaining, but just stops on check_buyer.php

Comment: sorry, i answer while i'm working :)

Try this :

1. move `logout()` function to **logout.php**.
2. move `validateUser()` and `isLoggedIn()` to **check_buyer.php**.
3. delete **login_helper.php** and remove line `include('login_helper.php');`
4. and make sure you uncomment again `session_regenerate_id();`

Comment: if you could please help arif! I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: I've updated my code to what i had and the error im incurring. Please see above code update.

Comment: have you tried my suggestion with four step above? and please make sure, in `validateUser()`, use `$_SESSION['valid']=1;` not `$_SESSION['valid']==1`;

see my last edited code above.

Comment: If I enter in correct credentials and login, it logs in and shows the `logout` link, but if click this `logout` link it throws this error: `Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session in logout.php on line 5`

`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by logout.php:5) in logout.php on line 6`

Comment: Line 5 and 6 are:     
`session_destroy();
header( 'Location: index.php' );`

Comment: I added a `session_start();` before the  `$_SESSION = array(); //destroy all of the session variables` this seemed to have fixed it.

Comment: Congratulation, finally it's solved. And you are right, that we should add `session_start();` whenever we want to access the `$_SESSION` variable (i forgot not add it in **logout.php**).

Comment: this is my Skype Name : **arif.rh405**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

Try `meta refresh` for page forwarding. After closing the php block, add some HTML code like;

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=index.php">
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>
```

Sometimes session doesn't work as it should when you use `header()` function for page forwarding.

Comment: if($_SESSION['valid'] = 1) this is the problem i guess. you have used a single = instead of ==

Comment: That seemed to fix the problem with not being able to logout, now I can, but now it seems I can't login....

Comment: try replacing all header("location:...") blocks with meta refresh. it really helped me in the past. if there are conditional redirection cases, just use a variable like $url at the top and use it in the meta refresh block at the bottom of your code.